# Integrating 2Checkout Payment Gateway in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I am trying to integrate 2Checkout payment gateway into my Spring Boot application, but I am having difficulty finding up-to-date and comprehensive documentation online. Can anyone provide guidance or share their experience with integrating 2Checkout and Spring Boot? What are the key steps involved and what resources would be helpful?